# How to parse JSX children

Tags: typescript, jsx

I have searched on internet. The create element is being called with children as string instead of object thanks for help

This is code

```
export function createElement(tag: string, props?: any, ...children: JSX.Element[]){
   let el = "<"+tag+">";

   if(props != undefined){
        for(let i of children){
            if(i == undefined)
                throw new Error("Excepted class got undefined");
            else{

            }
        }
   }
   el+= "</"+tag+">"; 

   return el;   
}
```

How can i make sure that children is not array of strings

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? It seems that you completely missed the idea behind react and jsx. You are returning a string after all.

Comment: i am trying to parse element as string it is not react it is custom jsxFactory

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you're trying to do. You want to check whether the items in `children` are not strings? then just do `if (typeof i !== "string") { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Parsing JSX string "on the fly" into the corresponding instances of `JSX.Element` is quite a feat and would most likely require playing around with tsc to transpile your generated string into corresponding classes. Unfortunately I have not seen any acceptable solution to this generic problem so far.

On the other hand in most cases I have seen you do not actually need to parse arbitrary JSX string. It applies when your are working with limited set of possible elements and they are instantiated in a similar fashion. In your example you possibly can get away with simple switch:

```
let ComponentClass;

switch(tag)
{
    case "MyComponent":
        ComponentClass = MyComponent;
    break;

    case "MyOtherComponent":
        ComponentClass = MyOtherComponent;
    break;

    // Other cases / default comes here
}

return <ComponentClass {...props}>{children}</ComponentClass>;
```